# How do I recover hard disk space used by Lightroom?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-lightroom

I had Lightroom installed and it was taking up around 25 GB of space on my C drive as backup of some sort. So I simply went and removed all the catalog files-which was only 2 MB- from the default location. It still didn't clear up the space. So I thought uninstalling Lightroom might help but even after uninstalling it, all the space is still used up. I am missing almost 30 GB, my C drive just has 64 KB of space left and I can barely run my pc. How do I recover that space? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that it's Lightroom is currently consuming your disk space. Not only Lr, I found that Adobe's usually take lots of space in C: as it's the default place where all the cache is stored.

- If you're sure that Lightroom is currently, you might want to **clear its cache**. You didn't give any information about your Lr version, but the tutorial could be found easily on google. [Here](http://www.lightroomfanatic.com/tutorials/advanced/why-and-how-to-clear-your-lightroom-cache/) is an example.
- Change the  **maximum cache size limit** and/or change your **default cache location** other than Windows drive.
- Delete your Unneeded Smart Previews, Developing History and 1:1 Previews.
- But you've uninstalled Lr, try to delete your Lr related things or empty your Recycle Bin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wish I could try that but my OS crashed before I could. Had to format the whole drive. Thank you nevertheless! ^_^

Comment: You're welcome. Hope that you won't get that disk space issue again too